# Create custom button with Swift by extending the UIButton class

Tags: ios, swift, class, uibutton, extend

I'm in the process of learning Swift and I have a basic question. I don't want to use a Storyboard and I want to create a button with code. At the moment, I code my button this way:

```
let button1: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "myImage.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button1.addTarget(self, action: "myMethod", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
button1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25) // then I add this button to a navigation control
```

This works, but I'm looking for something slightly different. That is: I want to create a class, I want to pass at least the image name, the method the button must call and the frame. Moreover, I want to instantiate the button in my ViewController whenever I want.

I found many posts here but no post was really useful (some code did not work).

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
enum SPBarButtonTypes {
    case openDrawer
    case loginInfo
}

class SPBarButtonFactory: NSObject {

    class func createBarButtonItemOfType (buttonType: SPBarButtonTypes, withTarget buttonTarget: AnyObject, andAction buttonAction: Selector) -> UIBarButtonItem {
        var returnButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        returnButton.target = buttonTarget
        returnButton.action = buttonAction

        switch buttonType {
            case .openDrawer:
                returnButton.image = UIImage(named: "ic_menu")
            case .loginInfo:
                returnButton.image = UIImage(named: "ic_info_outline")
        default: NSLog("Wrong BarButton type")
        }

        return returnButton
    }

}
```

**ADDED TO IMPROVE COMMENT**

It just "seams" like a class nested in another class, but it really is Swifts way to declare a class-method....

This line declares a class named SPBarButtonFactory

```
class SPBarButtonFactory...
```

This line declares a class-method of SPBarButtonFactory

```
class func createBarButtonItemOfType...
```

Comment: Does this make sense to you? Or should I describe it some more?

Comment: It's ok, I'm only a little bit surprised to see a class nested in another class   :-)

Comment: Ok, i instatieted it this way, it worked fine, thanks: `let btn = SPBarButtonFactory.createBarButtonItemOfType(.openDrawer,withTarget: self,andAction: "none")
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn`

Comment: yes, thats the right way to do it... have fun and take a look on my added content... Its important to know!!! :-)

Comment: Oh, so why they add the class keyword? Isn't func enough?

Comment: Oh, ok: "Instance methods, as described above, are methods that are called on an instance of a particular type. You can also define methods that are called on the type itself. These kinds of methods are called type methods. You indicate type methods by writing the static keyword before the method’s func keyword. Classes may also use the class keyword to allow subclasses to override the superclass’s implementation of that method (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_307)

Comment: Yes, but an instance method is not what is described in my answer... The one you see there is a class method, not an instance method... But the document you have there is the right one to learn it completely... So you are on a good way :-)

Comment: I suppose what you call a "class method" is what they call a "type method"